# Displaying img from laravel storage in react

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

After uploading img from react to laravel backend . i want to display it but its not showing
The img was uploaded correctly and the path was uploaded to database but when i try to display it. it doesnt work

```
React code 
`    useEffect(() => {
        axiosClient
            .get("/getItems")
            .then((data) => {
                setAllItem(data.data.items);
                console.log(data.data.items);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);

               {Item.length > 1 &&
                 Item.map((el) => (
                    <AllItem
                        key={el.id}
                        title={el.title}
                        price={el.price}
                        img={`../../../../../storage/images/${el.image}`}
                    />
                     ))}


`
```

if i import img from {../../../../storage....} and display it it work but not like this

it was fetched correctly so

Answer (score 0):

In the database you need to write the path that starts with `/storage/images/img.png` (non-absolute path). On the frontend side collect the full path `window.location.origin` (or another host) + `/storage/images/img.png`.

Also don't forget about
`php artisan storage:link` to create a link to the public directory. Without it, the files won't be accessible